# Compensated random measure

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, poisson-process

Given that $N_{t}$ is a Poisson random measure with $\mathbb{E}[N]=\lambda t$, then

$N_{t}-\lambda t$ is a martingale.

Okay, now I don't get why in every Poisson random measure they always get the compensated random measure.  What's the point of compensating a random process?  I ask this because I'm studying Ito's lemma applied to jump processes.

Thanks in advance.